If $y^2 - (x^2)y -2x=0, x, y >0$ and $\int \frac{(y-x^2)}{(x^2 +y)(y^2 +x)} dx=f(y) +C$ , where $c$ is a constant, find the value of $f'(y)$ at $x=1$.
I need help with this question:what I have done so far
$y^2 - (x^2)y -2x=0 \\
y-x^2 =\frac{2x}{y}...(1)$.
Substituting $1$ in integration I get $\int \frac{(2x)}{y(x^2 +y)(y^2 +x)} dx$. After this I am not sure how to proceed.

f(y) is an integral, don't forget what you get when you differentiate an integral.

thanks, missed that part

Suggestion: please make the title short, include problem statement in the question area.

The roots of the equation $y^2 - x^2y - 2x = 0$ are:
$y = \dfrac{1}{2}\left(x^2 \pm \sqrt{x^4 + 8x} \right)$
As $y, x > 0$, the only valid root is:
$y = \dfrac{1}{2}\left(x^2 + \sqrt{x^4 + 8x} \right)$
Similarly, solving for $x$, the only valid root would be:
$x = \dfrac{\sqrt{y^3 + 1} - 1}{y}$
Now, $f'(y) =  \dfrac{y - x^2}{(x^2 + y)(y^2 + x)}\dfrac{dx}{dy}$
Proceed from here.

What would follow this?Direct substitution? It'll lead to a monstrous integral...just add few more details.

Thanks for the suggestion. Hope the changes look good.

Yes thank you :)
